# Where or when to log exceptions in an MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, exception, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to follow lots of advice to just use a global `HandleErrorAttribute`, but this attribute seems to go straight to displaying the `Error` view, leaving me no place to log the exception. I don't believe the view is the right place for logging and other business logic.

I also have the option of overriding `OnException` in my `BaseController`, but am worried about a conflict with `HandleErrorAttribute`. If I override `OnException` as follows, leaving the exception unhandled, will it carry on through to `HandleErrorAttribute`?

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;
    var controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    logger.Error(exception, "Exception in controller '{0}': action '{1}'.", controller, action);
    filterContext.Exception = exception;
    //filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

Or how else do I go about logging the exception? I believe the above two methods save me from implementing a 'try-catch' on every action method, and with catching specific exceptions this could be quite some chore. I would also like to have the option to restart the application or something should a really catastrophic exception occur, and again `HandleErrorAttribute` doesn't leave much room for that.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, Global.asax is a good place to do that:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the exception object.
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

    // Handle Exception

    // Call Server.ClearError() if the exception is properly handled
}
```

Comment: The documentation for that is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.error(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes use Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
}
```

Comment: Shutting down the app was only an exceptional case. The main point of my question was about where to do exception logging. But thanks, I didn't know how to do a shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Check out StackExchange.Exceptional, an open source exception logger that is was created for and used by SO.

https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional